# WordPress update statement based on join 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two data tables

```
'wp_balance' table with column Balance, and userid
```

Another table:

```
 'wp_users' table with column userid and referredby
```

`userid` is common in both table where `referredby` is a different userid. I need to update `referredby` members Balance in `wp_balance` table where `wp_balance.userid=wp_users.userid`.

Comment: From my understanding regarding your question, you want to update `balance` in `wp_balance` and `referredby` in `wp_users`?

Comment: balance in wp_balance,   'referredby' is the user whos balance is going to be updated

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE wp_balance SET balance = $sum FROM wp_balance JOIN wp_users
               ON wp_balance.userid = wp_users.userid;"
```

Comment: thnks but it  is not taking the referredby column from wp_users basically referredby users balance will be updated

Comment: something like this  `where wp_users.referredby= (wp_balance.userid = wp_users.userid)`

Comment: Dude, since they have the same `user_id`, it will be the same record. So we say, for example we want to update the balance of `Jay` which is in the `referredby` column. It has the `user_id` right? And that `user_id` is the same as the one in the `wp_balance` table. So it is right to just equate the `user_id` present on both table, because that connects the record.